# Appending to a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've been attempting to add a value to the end of a list inside a dictionary using a different dictionary. The assignment is a little more complicated, so I have simplified the problem down to these three lines, but keep getting None as a result.

```
finley = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':[41,51,61]}
crazy_sauce = {'d':3}
print finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is fine but `print finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])` prints none since `finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])` returns none. you remove print here and add a `print finley['c']` in next line

```
finley = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':[41,51,61]}
crazy_sauce = {'d':3}
finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])
print finley['c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to print the `return` value of the `.append()` function, which is `None`. You need to print the `dict` value after the call to `.append()`, like so:

```
finley      = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':[41, 51 ,61]}
crazy_sauce = {'d':3}

finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])

print(finley['c'])
```

Where the output is the following list:

```
[41, 51, 61, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, but :

> Most functions, methods that change the items of sequence/mapping does
>   return None: list.sort, list.append, dict.clear.

So just use print dict in next line after you update the list in dict.

```
finley = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':[41,51,61]}
crazy_sauce = {'d':3}
finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])
print(finley)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `append()` method changes the list *in-place* - it *doesn't create and then return the changed (extended) list*, it doesn't return *anything* (which in Python means that it returns the `None` special value).

---

So you first change your nested list *in-place* (not assigning it to other variable):

```
finley['c'].append(crazy_sauce['d'])
```

and then print the changed outer directory:

```
print(finley)
```